# spring + hibernate кодировка

Tags: кодировка, hibernate

Выкладываю приложение: http://pivotal.io/

база их: ClearDB MySQL Database Spark DB

проблема: записывает в базу `????????` вместо кириллицы, если в базе кириллица - достает нормально.

если работать с базой напрямую - все нормально, и записывает, и достает в кириллице. и если подключаю свою базу - тоже все нормально

Настройки:

```
<!-- Настройки бина dataSource будем хранить в отдельном файле -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop> 
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Как данные попадают в базу?

Comment: попробуйте указать кодировку в строке `jdbc.driverClassName`. добавьте в ссылку на БД строку `?characterEncoding=UTF-8` или ту кодировку которую используете

Answer (score 3):

У меня была похожая проблема. Я перепробовал кучу советов с англоязычного StackOverflow. Пробовал все из [этой статьи](http://tarapun-java.blogspot.com/2011/01/mysqlhibernatespring.html), но ничего не помогло. В БД все равно записывались символы в виде `???? ??`. Моя проблема была в кодировке самого проекта, кодировка была windows-1251, а база данных utf8. Поменял кодировку проекта - все сразу заработало. В Intellij Idea это можно сделать `Setting->Editor->File Encodings`